# Are mixed discriminants and hyper-determinants the same thing?

Tags: determinants, tensor, hypercube

## Premise

Hello, I'm trying to learn more about [hyperdeterminants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdeterminant), but as I'm sifting through the literature I'm finding more and more papers on [Mixed discriminant](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379589900098) and I find their definitions extremely similar.

### Question

I'm struggling to understand the difference, if any, between the two formalisms, as I'm failing to identify a procedure to compute the hyperdeterminant of a given hyper-cube, while I'm finding numerous examples of techniques to compute mixed discriminant.

What is the difference, if any, between mixed discriminants and hyper-determinants of a hypercube? Is there any known algorithm to compute the hyperdeterminant of an hypercube?

### References

Some references I'm sifting through while researching this question:

- [Mixed discriminants of positive semidefinite matrices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379589900098)
- [Mixed Matrices: Irreducibility and Decomposition](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-8354-3_2)
- [A characterization of the mixed discriminant](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4798.pdf)
- [An efficient tree decomposition method for permanents and mixed discriminants](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03046.pdf)
- [Mixed discriminant](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.1012.pdf)
- [A simple polynomial time algorithm to approximate the permanent within a simply exponential factor](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9704218.pdf)
- [Hyperdeterminants](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-8176-4771-1_15)
- [Memoire sur les Hyperdeterminant](https://books.google.it/books?id=GAVCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=memoire+sur+les+hyperdeterminant&source=bl&ots=qoclvOhxlq&sig=ACfU3U06Qt7bBaqmAUeKCLFXcBVYR6G3Ig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMoIne1qXlAhXGyKQKHaz6AU0Q6AEwD3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=memoire%20sur%20les%20hyperdeterminant&f=false)

Comment: The technical term seems to be mixed discriminant (not mixed determinant). I recommend using the terminology from the literature in your post.  It may be that a difference is in application of the concept(s). Gerhard "Like Flathead Screwdrivers And Chisels" Paseman, 2019.10.18.

Comment: I have fixed the errors within the question that you have pointed out. Thank you!